# Curved lines turn to straight lines after sDNA preparation

Tags: line, sdna, curved

I am an architect, sometimes I need to use sDNA to analyze networks mapped in AutoCAD. But I met a problem with curved lines, i.e. circle, or polylines.

After importing .dwg file into .gdb, and using 'prepare' function of sDNA toolbox, all of the curved lines turns into straight lines with only starting and ending points. Is there any way to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you are using .dwg format which doesn't support XY Tolerance (which .gdb does). If tolerance is set too small, the points on the curve which are closer together than the tolerance level will be collapsed together, producing a straight line.

Once you have imported to .gdb, check the projection properties of the feature class and set tolerance to a sensible level which is further apart than the points on the curves. The usual default is 0.01 metres which should do the trick.